# How to authenticate user with FastAPI python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, fastapi

I am quite new to FastAPI. I heard it can get me results fast, thats why I choose the framework. I am building a simple api with a JSON file that contains some details. Here is the structure of the JSON below:

```
{'url': {'protocol': 'https',
  'host': 'some-website.com',
  'path': '/some-endpoint',
  'query': []},
 'method': 'POST',
 'header': [{'key': 'Authorization',
   'value': 'Bearer {some-very-long-code-with-letters-and-numbers'},
  {'key': 'Accept', 'value': 'application/json'}],
 'body': {'mode': 'raw',
  'raw': '{\n    "email": "minus",\n    "password": "eum"\n}'},
 'description': '',
 'response': []}
```

In the documentation I received email and password is required to authentic a user. Here is my approach with `FastAPI` below:

```
app = FastAPI(
    debug=True,
    title="some title",
    description="some description",
    version="some version",
)
```

After loading the JSON file as a data and save it with a variable called `data`

```
@app.post("/" + data[0]["item"][0]["request"]["url"]['path'])
async def authenticate_user(email, password):
    return requests.post(data[0]["item"][0]["request"]["url"]['protocol'] + "://" + data[0]["item"][0]["request"]["url"]['host'] + "/" + data[0]["item"][0]["request"]["url"]['path'], 
                        json=data[0]["item"][0]["request"]["header"][0], auth=(email, password))
```

This was only my idea and again this is my very first time using `FastAPI` so it might be an inefficient approach.
Running the code, when I enter an email and password and ran I get 500 error with the following trace:

```
File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 218, in app
    is_coroutine=is_coroutine,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 137, in serialize_response
    return jsonable_encoder(response_content)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 149, in jsonable_encoder
    sqlalchemy_safe=sqlalchemy_safe,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 96, in jsonable_encoder
    sqlalchemy_safe=sqlalchemy_safe,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 149, in jsonable_encoder
    sqlalchemy_safe=sqlalchemy_safe,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 96, in jsonable_encoder
    sqlalchemy_safe=sqlalchemy_safe,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 141, in jsonable_encoder
    raise ValueError(errors)
```

How can I solve this? I dont seem to understand the issue? And also running the code with url and endpoint I get method not allowed, I went through the docs to run it on the browser. Your time and contribution is greatly appreciated and welcome.

Comment: Check this doc https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/?h=beare#simple-oauth2-with-password-and-bearer

Comment: Aditional to @NicolasRondon comment, to use SQLAlchemy is good to understand how to work Pydantic and response_model. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/

Comment: I have a repo that using to learn, there has an auth implementation and SQLAlchemy. https://github.com/fike/fastapi-blog